# Using styled-jsx with postcss, styles not reloading/rebuilding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-jsx

I'm using postcss with styled-jsx. I have a few CSS files that I'm including using `@import` in `_app.js`. This works just fine, except when I make changes to the CSS files, Next.js doesn't rebuild the app. I kinda get that since it's likely not watching CSS files for changes. However, I can't do anything to make Next.js rebuild with the changes. I've tried changing and saving `_app.js`. I get a rebuild, but the changes aren't included. I can delete the `.next` folder and that works.  Here's what my includes look like:

```js
export default const App = ({Component, pageProps}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />

      <style jsx global>
        {`
          @import '@css/variables.css';
          @import '@css/mixins.css';
          @import '@css/reset.css';
          @import '@css/body.css';
          @import '@css/grid.css';
          @import '@css/form.css';
        `}
      </style>
    </>
  )
}
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add empty style in _app.js
like this

import 'nameofyourfile.css'

Comment: I've tried that as well, doesn't work. I've even split the imports into multiple `<style>` elements.

Comment: why you want add to _app.js you can have this import to your layout if have or import to globl .css or .sass file and import that one in _app.js

Comment: It doesn't matter where I import it, same problem. If I put all the imports in a single CSS file, I still have the same problem; Next.js won't rebuild/reload it.

Comment: Btw, I have a lot more code in `_app.js`, I'm just showing the minimal bit to reproduce this issue. I'm importing in `_app.js` instead of layout because I want to include that CSS for every layout.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by going a different route; probably the best-practice in this situation. I'll post my solution in case it's helpful.

I just used [next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css) (*see update at the bottom of the post*), and a javscript import to include the files. I'll post code below. I found a couple benefits to this way of doing it:

1. Next.js automatically catches changes and rebuilds.
2. Sourcemaps work better. Before, when I clicked on the source of a style in dev tools, it would just point me to my `<style>@import...` statement. Not helpful. **EDIT:** Actually, sourcemap seems to be broken for me. Something to do with postcss and next-css not playing well together, I think.

In the end, this is probably a better way to do it. Though, I'd still like to know if there's a resolution that works with what I posted originally.

#### _app.js

```js
@import 'path/to/global.css'

export default const App = ({Component, pageProps}) => {
  return (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
};
```

*To forestall questions, there is more to this file than I'm showing. Really just including it to show the difference between my original post and the solution.*

#### global.css

```css
@import '@css/variables.css';
@import '@css/mixins.css';
@import '@css/reset.css';
@import '@css/body.css';
@import '@css/grid.css';
@import '@css/form.css';
```

#### next.config.js

```js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({})
```

**UPDATE (01/26/20):** Next.js 9.2 now has built-in support for importing CSS files. So you can get rid of the `next-css` stuff. Plus it fixes sourcemaps; so that works great.